# Does java support multiple inheritance?

Tags: java

Does java support multiple inheritance? 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkhMD.png)

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about classes and one class extend 2 other classes at the same time, the answer is no.

But, If you are using Java 8, you can achieve multiple inheritance with interfaces with default methods.

Check this here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-and-multiple-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**.

But developers still wanted something similar so they created **interface**s! A class can implement as many interfaces as you want!

A better explanation of what interfaces are, and how they can be used can be found at [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).